# Create gift certificate using Ultracart API

Tags: shopping-cart, ultracart

I am new to Ultracart checkout api. I have developed an shopping cart system using Ultracart api and need to create gift certificate for certain amount. and I have to do this by using api. Please suggest me whether it is possible using api or not. Is there any other alternative to accomplish this task. Please help.